# Ransack custom default sort

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, ransack

After spending the second half of my day on this hopefully just in need of some fresh eyes. Getting this error while [trying to set a default](https://github.com/ernie/ransack/wiki/Sorting-in-the-Controller) sort for my index controller using ransack and I'm not sure why

```
undefined method `split' for #<Post:0x007fabedac69a8>
```

Here is my controller

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @search = Post.search(params[:q])
    @search.sorts = Post.find_with_reputation(:votes,:all, order: "votes desc") if @search.sorts.empty?
    @posts = @search.results
  end
end
```

Using active record reputation and want the default load to sort by highest votes as you can see. Maybe there is a better way to achieve have the page load with sorted votes and allow ransack searching? Thoroughly confused at the moment.

Comment: `@search.sorts` what is it?

Comment: `find_with_reputation` where it is written can you please post it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of *@search.sort* try to assign it into another variable. Also instead of *results* use *result*

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @search = Post.search(params[:q])
    @search_r = Post.find_with_reputation(:votes,:all, order: "votes desc") if @search.sorts.empty?
    @posts = @search_r.result
  end
end
```